# Copying content from other(news) website?

Tags: seo, google

I copied the news article from different sources for more than 2 years and now I'm copying the content & specifying the canonical URL of source websites(hope this is the correct way to do it [**correct me if I'm wrong**]). but my question is what should I do to the previous posts, I have no idea on where I copied those articles and obviously it have more than 2000 pages, So I'm unable to do canonical tag for the previous posts, how should I fix this ? (or) will I leave those articles as it is ? please suggest me a solution!

Please don't mark duplicate with [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site) I already read that post, here my situation is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use a [meta tag noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) in these old pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

These pages will be removed from index of search engines (if it's not already the case) but your site won't be penalized (if it's not already the case).

Comment: I'm going to apply the noindex tag for all news articles pages globally, do I need to specify the canonical URL of source websites in future?

Comment: If you apply the `noindex` for all pages, you're not obliged to insert the `rel="canonical"` tag too (because the duplicate content problem is already solved by the `noindex`).